# How can I start Emacs from the command line on Android?

Tags: android

The reason I want this, is that I need to run with --debug-init

First, I find the package name

```
$adb shell pm list packages |grep -i emac
package:org.gnu.emacs
```

Then I try to start it

```
$ adb shell am start -n org.gnu.emacs
Exception occurred while executing 'start':
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad component name: org.gnu.emacs
        at android.content.Intent.parseCommandArgs(Intent.java:8828)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.makeIntent(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:398)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.runStartActivity(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:506)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.onCommand(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:222)
        at com.android.modules.utils.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:97)
        at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:38)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onShellCommand(ActivityManagerService.java:11206)
        at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:1085)
        at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:903)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:5643)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3135)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1321)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1280)
```

It says I need the ActivityName, but how can I find that?;)

```
$ adb shell am start -n org.gnu.emacs/.MainActivity
Starting: Intent { cmp=org.gnu.emacs/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {org.gnu.emacs/org.gnu.emacs.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

EDIT: I've installed Emacs from F-Droid.

Comment: What is the source of the Android Emacs package you have installed (what project)?

Comment: "*The reason I want this, is that I need to run with --debug-init*" I have a feeling that this might be an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/241919) considering that Android apps are not the same as console apps, meaning that starting Emacs Android app from the command line might not be what you want since you cannot put the flags similar to starting console apps. That said, the main activity is `org.gnu.emacs.EmacsActivity`. (Note: I only know about Android in general, having no Emacs knowledge)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do:

```
adb shell am start -n org.gnu.emacs/org.gnu.emacs.EmacsActivity
```

;)